# What does "ripping" mean in the context of stock trading?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here's a sentence I don't understand:

> I buy the stock when it is ripping.

The sentence is talking about buying a stock (i.e. equity shares) when it is "ripping". What does "ripping" mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is stockmarket slang, and not general use

According to [vantage point trading](https://vantagepointtrading.com/basic-day-trading-terms-every-day-trader-should-know/#:%7E:text=Rip%20Definition,refers%20to%20a%20trading%20fee.)

> ''Rip'' A dramatic upward move in the price of an asset, relative to surrounding price moves.

Compare with the slightly better known "Tanking" (to dramatically drop in value)

It is related to the common meaning "To move or act fast, to rush headlong."  [(Wiktionary sense 11)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rip#Verb)

Comment: "ripping" means "rallying"?

Comment: I (native speaker) didn't know this meaning and don't remember ever hearing it. (I trust the answer though.) I wonder if this use derives from [surfer slang](https://www.stokedsurfschool.com/blog/2016/01/17/surfer-slang-101#:~:text=Turning%20on%20the%20lip%20of,grom%20-%20he%20absolutely%20rips!")?

Comment: I don't know if this use is derived from the term **rip tide/current** – a rapid movement of tidal water but not particularly surfer slang – there were tides and sailors long before there was surfer slang.

Comment: Yes, in board sports (surfing, snowboarding, skateboarding, parasailing, etc.)  to rip, means to ride aggressively http://alpineobjectives.com/skiing-snowboarding-slang-for-dummies. Here,it means appreciating fast. Going up in value.

Comment: @Flux To rally is to recover: what went down is now coming back up. Rip seems to apply to a fast but isolated upward movement.